# button Highlighted not work when interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES

Tags: ios, popviewcontroller

Use interactivePopGestureRecognizer when popViewController.

Set Custom back button and keep interactivePopGestureRecognizer = YES.

```
- (void)setNavigation {
   [self.navigationController.scrollNavigationBar setNavigationTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

   UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"]
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(popViewController)];
   backButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;

   self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
}
```

have a likeButton on the ViewController.

```
- (YMFeedLikeButton *)likeButton {
if (!_likeButton) {
    YMFeedLikeButton *likeButton = [[YMFeedLikeButton alloc] init];
        replyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 50, 150, 50);
    [likeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topic-icon-like.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [likeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topic-icon-like.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [likeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topic-icon-liked.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [likeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topic-icon-liked.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateHighlighted];

    UIImage *highlight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"highlight.png"];
    [likeButton setBackgroundImage:highlight
                          forState:UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected];
    [likeButton setBackgroundImage:highlight
                          forState:UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateNormal];
    [likeButton setBackgroundImage:highlight
                          forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(like)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [likeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:170.0f/255.0f green:170.0f/255.0f blue:170.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [likeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:170.0f/255.0f green:170.0f/255.0f blue:170.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]
                     forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [likeButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -30, 0, 0)];
    likeButton.value = 0;
    [self insertSubview:_likeButton = likeButton atIndex:0];
}
return _likeButton;
```

}

likeButton `Highlighted` is not working when i clicked it.

If close `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

or change `likeButton.frame = CGRectMake(150, 150, 150, 50);`

,likeButton `Highlighted` touch is working.

i hope likeButton `Highlighted` is working when used`interactivePopGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: is the like button action "`like`" fired on touching the like button?

Comment: @GoGreen the like button change backgroundview when touching.

Comment: when you set self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;, is the buton action `like` fired? please test using breakpoint.

Comment: @GoGreen if interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES,likeButton not Highlighted when i touching it.

Comment: I get that. I was just confirming whether it has nothing to do with highlight alone. maybe the button action is being fired. please check that too.

Comment: and from the button frame, I think you are trying to place the reply button at the bottom left corner of the screen. are you using a tab bar ?

Comment: if you have a tab bar and you are hiding it, then you might face this issue.

Comment: @GoGreen yep,i tried,the button not highlight when only at the bottom left corner of the screen.

Comment: @GoGreen  button can highlight, when change button.frame at the bottom right corner of the screen or  top of the screen.

Comment: if button at bottom left and `interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO` will it work?

Comment: @GoGreen yes, work at enabled = NO .  it not work when at bottom left && enabled = YES.

Comment: that is so strange. ok. so are you using a tab bar?

Comment: @GoGreen yes,i hiding it. is truth...you can creat a new project to have a test....

Comment: I think thats where the problem comes. Instead of placing the button relative to the window, try placing it relative the superView. such as `replyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 150, 50);`

Comment: @GoGreen i  can 't solve this problems. :)

Comment: did you try like I said?

Comment: @GoGreen yap, replyButton is not work too...

Comment: This is very strange indeed. Please inform if you find the solution to this problem.

Comment: @GoGreen i will. if i find...

Answer (score 0):

It's late, but anyway... This solution works for me:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
```